# Laravel 4 Resource Controllers: How to manage non collection resources

Tags: rest, laravel-4

Say I have the following restful URIs:

```
api/v1/users/username1
api/v1/users/username2
api/v1/users/username3
```

Laravel supports resource controllers and routes for the above URIs. I'm not sure my terminology is correct, but I like to refer to these types of URIs as collection based i.e. `api/v1/users` would show a list of users, `api/v1/users/{username}` shows a particular user of the users collection.

But what if we have the following URIs;

```
api/v1/users/username1/profile
api/v1/users/username2/profile
api/v1/users/username3/profile
```

I like to call these resources 'singular' resources i.e they are not part of a collection. Each user has a singular profile.

My question: Is there a way to code for this in laravel resource controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the route before/after the resource controller:

```
  Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
  Route::get('api/v1/users/{user}/profile', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

Also - I recommend you read this blog post by Phil Sturgeon called "[Beware the Route to Evil](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil/)" for some ideas about not using resource controllers.

Comment: ah, ok. So no way to handle in the resource controller/route. Just need to create a regular route? Imagine this is going to get messy if i need to nest resource controllers e.g. api/v1/users/{user}/profile/addresses/{id}

Comment: Hence the blog post from Phil - just organise your routes in the `routes.php`. It is easier to have full control than defaulting to resource controllers

Comment: Have just skim read blog and I agree with the points. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.